# Docker "clean start"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, restart

I use Docker for development a HW-SW system where restarts and power losses happen very often. I'd like to find away to ignore/destroy all containers that were running at the time of shutdown and start Docker from the scratch (using docker-compose).
--force-recreate option of docker-compose, which seemed applicable - has some issues, such as "stuck" "old" port mappings preventing a new container instances from being run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
docker system prune
```

to remove unused images, containers and networks. That should help remove the old port mappings.

Comment: I do not want to remove an images - and "fallen" containers do not considered "unused" by "prune"

Answer (score 0):

Typically you can start the container with `--rm` flag, so it will remove container once it stops or system shutdown.
But I did not found a similar flag for docker-compose, you can try the below but it will work manually not on shutdown or reboot

```
Usage: rm [options] [SERVICE...]

Options:
    -f, --force   Don't ask to confirm removal
    -s, --stop    Stop the containers, if required, before removing
    -v            Remove any anonymous volumes attached to containers
```

[docker-comose rm](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/rm/)

So the workaround is to run cron job on `bootup` and remove all container.

`remove_container.sh`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# put sleep so the docker process ready
sleep 90
# remove all container
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

cronjob

```
@reboot (sh /home/user/remove_container.sh)
```

You can add a similar option for window etc, the above one tested on Ubuntu distribution.